# Setting over- and underbraces outside an matrix formula

Tags: math-mode, matrices, braces

I want to typeset a matrix which consists of several submatrices. As they consist of some longer formulae I'd like to assign each a name. I tried to use `\underbace` and `\overbrace`. However now the braces and the letter appears inside the matrix and I'd like to have it above or below the matrix. What would you suggest here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
H_{8kl}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    \overbrace{\sfrac{1}{2} (A+B)\otimes E + \sfrac{1}{2} (A-B)\otimes G}^{K} &
    \overbrace{\sfrac{1}{2} (A+B)\otimes F + \sfrac{1}{2} (A-B)\otimes H}^{L}\\
    \underbrace{\sfrac{1}{2} (C+D)\otimes E + \sfrac{1}{2} (C-D)\otimes G}_{M} &
    \underbrace{\sfrac{1}{2} (C+D)\otimes F + \sfrac{1}{2} (C-D)\otimes H}_{M}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I `\smash`ed the over and undersets, so that the matrix would not know of them.  However, I had to compensate with a leading rule to accound for the vertical space that was smashed (the three `4ex` expressions in the `\rule` can be changed in size to increase or decrease the gap above/below the expression).

Struts had to be added *outside* the over- and under-sets so as to get the parens to set to the right vertical size and also *inside* the over- and under-sets to get the braces to stand off from the expression appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{gather*}
\rule[\dimexpr-4ex-\ht\strutbox]{0pt}{\dimexpr4ex+4ex+\baselineskip}
 H_{8kl}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    \strut\smash{\overbrace{\strut\sfrac{1}{2} (A+B)\otimes E + \sfrac{1}{2} (A-B)\otimes G}^{K}} &
    \strut\smash{\overbrace{\strut\sfrac{1}{2} (A+B)\otimes F + \sfrac{1}{2} (A-B)\otimes H}^{L}}\\
    \strut\smash{\underbrace{\strut\sfrac{1}{2} (C+D)\otimes E + \sfrac{1}{2} (C-D)\otimes G}_{M}} &
    \strut\smash{\underbrace{\strut\sfrac{1}{2} (C+D)\otimes F + \sfrac{1}{2} (C-D)\otimes H}_{M}}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use explicit sizing instructions -- e.g., `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` -- for the parentheses that surround the matrix. To simplify the overall look of the matrix, you may also want to factor out the common term `0.5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "matrix" environment
\begin{document}
\[
H_{\textit{8kl}}= \frac{1}{2}
\Biggl( \, \begin{matrix} 
    \overbrace{ (A+B)\otimes E +  (A-B)\otimes G}^{K} &
    \overbrace{ (A+B)\otimes F +  (A-B)\otimes H}^{L}\\[1ex]
    \underbrace{ (C+D)\otimes E +  (C-D)\otimes G}_{M} &
    \underbrace{ (C+D)\otimes F +  (C-D)\otimes H}_{M}
\end{matrix} \, \Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```