# How to represent a big border matrix in latex?

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

[image]

I have tried a little, but getting confused how to represent the big curly braces on the top of the matrix? The MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % <-- You already load mathtools?!
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blkarray} % <-- Twice!
\usepackage{mathtools} % Loads amsmath too
%\usepackage{easybmat}
%\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
%\usepackage{blkarray} % <-- Twice!
\begin{document}
\[
ETC =
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
& T_{11} & T_{12} & \cdots & T_{1_{|T1|}} \\
\begin{block}{@{}ccccc}
C_{1} & ETC_{11,1} & ETC_{12,1} & \cdots & ETC_{1|T_{1}|,1}  \\
C_{2} & ETC_{11,2} & ETC_{12,2} & \cdots & ETC_{1|T_{1}|,2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
C_{n} & ETC_{11,m} & ETC_{12,m} & \cdots & ETC_{1|T_{1}|,m} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not call a non-compilable-document a MWE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Now, It has been taken care.

Comment: I cleaned the MWE of packages that are not needed to compile your code. I also pointed put some strange stuff. Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108009 or this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130798 or this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185093? There are a lot of questions regarding *overbracing* and *matrices*.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately it didn't help me.